# Remove String node from single linked list java

Tags: java, string, singly-linked-list

Hello I'm learning singly linked list and I'm using an example from a java book, I'm trying to delete a node given an string value. I already coded but i doesnt delete anything, anyone can give me any advice? Im already frustrated because I dont know what Im doing wrong. Thanks.

```
   public class LinkedStringLog implements StringLogInterface {
  protected LLStringNode log; // reference to first node of linked 
                              // list that holds the StringLog strings
  protected String name;      // name of this StringLog

  public LinkedStringLog(String name)
  // Instantiates and returns a reference to an empty StringLog object 
  // with name "name".
  {
    log = null;
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void remove(String element){
  LLStringNode currentNode;
  LLStringNode temporal;
  currentNode = log;
  temporal = currentNode.getLink();

  if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(currentNode.getInfo())){
      log = currentNode.getLink();

  } 

 while(currentNode!=null){
      if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(currentNode.getInfo())){
          temporal.setLink(currentNode.getLink());
      }
      else{
          currentNode.getLink();
          temporal = currentNode;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're entering in a infinite loop, because you're not updating `currentNode` variable in the `while` loop.

You may want something like this:

```
while(currentNode!=null){
      if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(currentNode.getInfo())){
          //don't you want to update the link of the node before currentNode here?
      }
      else{
          currentNode = temporal; //update currentNode variable
          temporal = currentNode.getLink(); //update temporal variable
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have *many* errors.

One of the main issues was that you failed to maintain a `prevNode` reference as you traverse the linked list, so you were not able to keep all the items in the list linked together.

Also, where do you set `log` to the head item of the linked list?

In any case, this version of `remove` might work better (as long as `log` is actually non-null):

```
     public void remove(String element) {
         if (log == null) {
             return;
         }
         LLStringNode currentNode = log;
         LLStringNode prevNode = null;

         while (currentNode != null) {
             LLStringNode nextNode = currentNode.getLink();
             if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(currentNode.getInfo())) {
                 if (currentNode.equals(log)) {
                     log = nextNode;
                 }
                 if (prevNode != null) {
                     prevNode.setLink(nextNode);
                 }
             } else {
                 prevNode = currentNode;
             }
             currentNode = nextNode;
         }
     }
```